# How can I assign a declarative function to an expression without repeating code?

Tags: javascript

ie:

```
function A() {
  //code inside here that I don't want to repeat.
};

self.A = A;
```

I can't rename the declarative form function because if I do that whatever's calling that form will no longer work, and I need the self expression so I can access the function from another file.

Comment: I don't see where you are repeating code? Surely writing `A` cannot be seen as duplicate?

Comment: A() will have stuff in it, it doesn't matter what's inside, I just don't want to duplicate what's inside...

Comment: But you only have `A()` once? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to repeat the function name as a property, you can use `Object.assign` and an object initializer with shorthand property names:

```js
(() => {
  function A() { }
  Object.assign(self, {A});
  console.log(self.A === A); // true
})();
```

Comment: I don't have access to the AMD module dependecy. Is there a better way to do this?